# jeditable datepicker causing blur when changing month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a jquery-ui datepicker inside of jeditable.  Changing the month causes a blur. In order to be able to keep functioning after the blur, I had to set settings.onblur="cancel"

But I need it to "cancel" in the case of an actual blur.

Has anyone run into this issue?

edit:

i just hacked jeditable with:

```
  monthChangeButtonClicked = function(blurEvent) { 
    return blurEvent.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.innerHTML == "Prev" || 
    blurEvent.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.innerHTML == "Next"; }
  if (monthChangeButtonClicked(e)) return;
```

Such a nasty hack :(

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this same issue when changing the month.

I tweeked the code that sets up the custom input type, to handle the onblur event there.  This seems to work:

```
jQuery.editable.addInputType('datepicker', {
  element: function(settings, original) {

      var input = jQuery('<input size=8 />');


      // Catch the blur event on month change
      settings.onblur = function(e) { 
            t = setTimeout(function() {
            reset.apply(form, [settings, self]);
            }, 500);
         };

      input.datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          jQuery(this).parents("form").submit();
        },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
           jQuery(this).parents("form").submit();
        },

      });

      input.datepicker('option', 'showAnim', 'slide');

      jQuery(this).append(input);
      return (input);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [jeditable-datepicker](https://github.com/qertoip/jeditable-datepicker) plugin seems to do exactly what you need.

It enables jQuery UI Datepicker in Jeditable. Here's the [demo](http://thesingularity.pl/jeditable-datepicker-demo).